# Split multi value cellson Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Spreadsheet that record information in 3 columns. The first columns record in one cell several names separated by `;`, like this:

```
A                                                   B       C
Mieke Jans;Jan r Werf;Nadine Lybaert;Koen Vanhoof   2011    Belgium
Alessandro Stefanini;Davide Aloini                  2020    Italy
Worarat Krathu;Davide Aloini;Robert Engel           2014    Austria
Jasmien Lismont                                     2016    Belgium
```

I want to apply a function to column A such that the function splits the information on the `;`. Something like:

```
=SPLITTING_FUNCTION(A:A)
```

that results in

```
Mieke Jans
Jan r Werf
Nadine Lybaert
Koen Vanhoof 
Alessandro Stefanini
Davide Aloini
Worarat Krathu
Davide Aloini
Robert Engel
Jasmien Lismont
```

Please observe that column A stores a variable number of names. Also, names can repeat. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) all the values in the range together by `;` and then [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) them by `;`:

```
=transpose(split(Join(";",transpose(A1:A)),";"))
```

[image]